# autogen.sh not working on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

I installed Ubuntu on Windows, then cloned https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin in.

```
cd bitcoin
./autogen.sh
```

Which returned this:

```
: not foundh: 5: ./autogen.sh:
./autogen.sh: 6: set: Illegal option -
```

What am I doing wrong here? Have I missed something, or do I need to raise it as an issue on GitHub?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `autogen.sh` is an `sh` script, not a `bash` script. What happens if you run `sh autogen.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

This means your file has DOS newlines thus, hidden CR characters at the end.
Thus, `set -e` becomes `set -e$'\r'` (using bash-specific syntax to represent the CR character), which isn't a valid option.

To fix this, if you have dos2unix installed, you can run:
    `dos2unix autogen.sh`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved the issue using Git in Windows.  Note that it will reset your local with master.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I was then able to use the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows to run ./autogen.sh without the error in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you're in the wrong directory as in the `bitcoin` directory there is definitely the `autogen.sh`.

Are you sure you are in the same `bitcoin` directory that you had just cloned? What does `ls` (list directory contents) return?